# How to sort files from directory in a array in php

Tags: php, file

I have the following code:

```
$imageDir = "uploads/";
$allowedTypes = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
$dimg = opendir($imageDir);
$images = array();

while ($imgfile = readdir($dimg)) {
    if (in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile, -3)), $allowedTypes) || (in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile, -4)), $allowedTypes))) {
        $images[] = $imgfile;

    }
}
```

Basically what I need is also order the images in the $images array. For example I have 
image-1.png, image-2.png, image-23.png, image-3.png , I want them stored in the correct order in my $images array (1, 2, 3, 23) not (1, 2, 23, 3).

Comment: there's a natural number sort in php, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`natsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function built into PHP. This will sort them from least to greatest (in terms of numbers), numbers before letters, and so on. If you need to sort them in the opposite order, you can use an [`array_reverse`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) after the sort.

Here is an example:

```
natsort($dirs); // Naturally sort the directories
$dirs = array_reverse($dirs); // Reverse the sorting
```

Comment: In one go: `rsort($filepaths, SORT_NATURAL);`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) here, which sorts alphanumeric strings the way a human would.

You should also split on the last `.` if you're going to be trusting file extensions (but let's not get into that. You should really be checking the mime type, but that's additional work you can do as homework)

```
$image_dir = "uploads/";
$allowed_types = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
$dimg = opendir($image_dir); // I vehemently follow my own style guide.
$images = array('png' => [], 'jpg' => [], 'jpeg' => [], 'gif' => []);
// all these people using pure array() when we've had the shorthand since php4...

while ($img_file = readdir($dimg)) {
    $ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $img_file))); // end() is fun.
    if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {
        $images[$ext][] = $img_file;
    }
}
foreach ($images as &$images_) { // pass-by-reference to change the array itself
    natsort($images_);
}

// $images is now sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
$imageDir = "uploads/";
$allowedTypes = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
$images = scandir($imageDir);

usort($images, function($file1, $file2){
    preg_match('/^image-(\d+)\./', $file1, $num1);
    preg_match('/^image-(\d+)\./', $file2, $num2);
    return $num1 < $num2 ? -1 : 1;
});

echo '<pre>' . print_r($images, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: there's no real need to make a custom function for this when a builtin does it perfectly already, honestly. but bonus for effort.